# semantic_fields_for doesn't group all into one li

Tags: ruby-on-rails, formtastic

I'm using f.semantic_fields_for with haml

here is the current snippet.

```
      %ul.documents
        =f.semantic_fields_for :documents do |u|
          = link_to(u.object.comment.presence || u.object.file.original_filename, u.object.file.url)                                                                                     
          = u.input :comment, :as=>:string
          = u.hidden_field :_destroy
          = link_to_function image_tag("/img/del_documets.png"), "remove_fields(this)", :class => "btn"
```

the problem here is that only "u.input :comment, :as=>:string" is inside the "li" created by formtastic. The links and other fields get somewhere else and its kinda impossible to style correctly this broken html.

Is there anyway to make sure everything get inside the correct li?

Even if I add a li just after f.semantic_fields_for, it will only wrap the first link and the following elements will get wrapped only by the ul completely above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like formtastic always wraps inputs with `<li>` to avoid `<fieldsets>` to be inside `<ol>`, which is not valid.

Your best way around that is to put `<li>` around all your elements and add `wrapper_html => { :class => :your_class }` to your input if you like. That way you can style things your way.

I don't think you need the `ul.documents` around the inputs, `semantic_fields_for` already wraps everything using `<ol>`.

That't the thing with libraries that generate html directly, you'd better adapt your html and css to them instead of trying to make them generate your html.

I would do that (and style my own CSS from it):

```
    =f.semantic_fields_for :documents do |u|
      %ul.documents
        %li= link_to(u.object.comment.presence || u.object.file.original_filename, u.object.file.url)                                                                                     
        = u.input :comment, :as=>:string
        %li= u.hidden_field :_destroy
        %li= link_to_function image_tag("/img/del_documets.png"), "remove_fields(this)", :class => "btn"
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: The problem with that is that all my element must be in one line. this gives me four LIs, while I can probably wrap these for LIs in a UL but yeah that's quite ugly

Comment: also the hidden_field doesn't get wrapped by a li

Answer (score 1):

You could also override the default behavior of Formtastic when it generates the `inputs` wrapper like this:

```
module Formtastic
  module Inputs
    module Base
      module Wrapping
        def input_wrapping(&block)
          template.content_tag(:li,
            [template.capture(&block), error_html, hint_html].join("\n").html_safe, 
            wrapper_html_options
          )
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Notice the `content_tag(:li`. You could replace it by `content_tag(:div` for example.

You know how to override module methods in Rails?

Comment: that's probably a way to get a nice result, but I'd need to pass a parameter to the input in order to not change the default behavior. I upvote anyway since I don't have much time changing everything